# PageController is always giving idle as a result pageController.position.userScrollDirection

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

#### Page Controller: Custom Scrolling

PageController is giving always giving idle as a result pageController.position.userScrollDirection.
I want to create a scrolling effect where I will only be able to scroll to the next or the previous page by uusing pageview but pageview is scrolling multiple pages. I used the page controller but AxisDirection is always giving the direction as down and userScrolldurection is giving Idle. Please help me with this.

Code:

```dart
import 'package:ed_cell/main.dart';
import 'package:ed_cell/registration_form.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ed_cell/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ed_cell/userinfo_page.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState myHomePageState = new _MyHomePageState();
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => myHomePageState;
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 2);
    pageController.addListener(() {
      changepage();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  changepage() {
    if (pageController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward) {
      print('down');
      setState(() {
        pageController.animateToPage(pageController.page.toInt() + 1,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
      });
    }
    if (pageController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.idle) {
      print('Idle');
    }

    if (pageController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      print('up');
      setState(() {
        pageController.animateToPage(pageController.page.toInt() - 1,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthService>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) {
      return PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: pageController,
        children: [
>Padding(
>Padding(
>Padding(       
 ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Idle
Idle
Idle
Idle
Idle
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-IN)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding the logic in the listener, you can wrap your `Pageview` with a `NotificationListener` widget which can intercept all the notifications from its child widget as shown below.

> I moved your logic from `changePage` method to the `onNotification` callback. Also change the animation duration to 1000 milliseconds to proove it works.

A fully working example can be found here in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/JjGLyyP).

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        if(notification is UserScrollNotification){
          if (notification.direction ==
            ScrollDirection.forward) {
          print('down');
          setState(() {
            pageController.animateToPage(pageController.page.toInt() - 1,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
          });
        }
        if (notification.direction ==
            ScrollDirection.idle) {
          print('Idle');
        }

        if (notification.direction ==
            ScrollDirection.reverse) {
          print('up');
          setState(() {
            pageController.animateToPage(pageController.page.toInt() + 1,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
          });
        }
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: pageController,
        children: [
          Center(child: Container(child: Text('Page 1......'))),
          Center(child: Container(child: Text('Page 2......'))),
          Center(child: Container(child: Text('Page 3......'))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```